# Oracle - Using a Case Statement with Count

Tags: oracle

I have the below piece of query and it runs but not producting what I want.

Query:

```
select id
,CASE WHEN COUNT(id ) > 1  THEN 'X'
 ELSE  ' ' END AS Dual
from x
group by id
```

Results:

```
ID    Dual
1      
1
```

I would like to see:

```
ID       Dual
1         x
1         x
```

Comment: Is that your entire query? Why are you expecting to see multiple rows with ID = 1 if you are grouping by ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE x ( id INT );
INSERT INTO X VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO X VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO X VALUES (2);
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT id,
       CASE WHEN COUNT(1) OVER ( PARTITION BY id ) > 1
            THEN 'X'
            ELSE ' '
            END AS Dual
FROM   x;
```

**Output**:

```
        ID DUAL
---------- ----
         1 X    
         1 X   
         2
```

Answer (score 1):

If your table x has two rows, both with id = 1, as you seem to imply, then that is NOT the result of your query. You wouldn't get two rows with id = 1 with the group by id clause. Please clarify.

```
SQL> create table x (id) as select 1 from dual union all select 1 from dual;
Table created.
Elapsed: 00:00:00.01

SQL> select * from x;
        ID
----------
         1
         1
2 rows selected.
Elapsed: 00:00:00.08

SQL> select id
  2  ,CASE WHEN COUNT(id ) > 1  THEN 'X'
  3   ELSE  ' ' END AS Dual
  4  from x
  5  group by id
  6  /

        ID DUAL
---------- ----
         1 X
1 row selected.
Elapsed: 00:00:00.13
```